# Query/return records with dates between Sunday and Saturday?

Tags: asp.net, sql, vb.net

I've searched this site and others, but couldn't find this exact scenario. I need to add a gridview to my page where the sqldatasource is based on a query that returns records that fall between Sunday and Saturday of the current week. (Each record has one date field) The records are for payroll purposes and the payroll week runs from Sunday to Saturday. I need to find all records that fall in the current pay week. Can anyone point me in the right direction to get started? I'm coding in VB.

Answer (score 1):

This is a SQL question so you should tag it accordingly with your dbms.

Assuming you're using SQL-Server, [`DATEPART`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174420.aspx) can be used to get  the weekday as `int` of a `datetime` field and [`DATENAME`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174395.aspx) can be used to get the name of the weekday.

For example(assuming *Sunday to Saturday* actually means from Monday to Friday):

```
SELECT t.*
FROM YourTable t
WHERE DATEPART(weekday, YourDateField) BETWEEN 2 AND 6
```

Note that it [depends on regional settings](http://ryanfarley.com/blog/archive/2005/02/14/1685.aspx) what is the first day of the week.

**Edit**:  If you want to select records from the current week.

```
SELECT t.*
FROM YourTable t
WHERE YourDateField >= DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, GETDATE()) / 7 * 7, 0)
AND YourDateField < DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, -1, GETDATE()), 0)
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819.aspx

Comment: Ok, so I implemented your second suggestion and it's working. However, it's filtering Monday-Sunday instead of Sunday-Saturday.

Comment: Ok, so I modified the SQL and appear to have it working now between Sunday and Saturday. (See next comment for code) Only problem is it won't display any records for the current week beyond the current day. For example, give week Sunday 03/18 through Saturday 03/24, if I run the query on 03/20, I can't see any records past 03/20 even if they exist. (ie: 03/21, 03/22, 03/23 and 03/24) Is there any way to resolve this issue and display any records that fall within that Sunday/Saturday week regardless of the current day?

Comment: SELECT t.* FROM YourTable t WHERE YourDateField >= DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, -1, GETDATE()) / 7 * 7, -1) AND YourDateField < DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, -1, GETDATE()), 0)

Comment: Found what appears to be a simplified way to achieve the desired result.

datediff(wk,[ColumnName],getdate())=0

This is working wonderfully so far. Thanks to those who provided suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you are searching a way to get the working time of an employee between two date
(from sunday to saturday). You need the exact date of Sunday before today.
This could be done via this function

```
Public  Function FirstWeekDay(d as DateTime)  As DateTime
    While(d.DayOfWeek <> DayOfWeek.Sunday)
        d.AddDays(-1)
    End While
    return d
End Function
```

The date returned is your startDate while your endDate depends where you want to stop your search.
According to your question this date is the following Saturday. Simply add 6 days to the startDate.
Now it's only a matter to pass the correct parameters to your query/storedprocedure:

```
SELECT w.* FROM workTime w WHERE w.empID = @empID AND w.workDate BETWEEN @startDate AND @endDate
```